# Dequeueing from a generic type queue, null pointer exception?

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null, queue

I am trying to make it dequeue the front node and print it out, however I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>      at MyQueue.toString(MyQueue.java:25)
>      at TestQueue.main(TestQueue.java:13)

From the `TestQueue` class, I am expecting the outputs 1 then after dequeueing 1 again, then finally 2 from the second `toString` call.

```
public class TestQueue {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyQueue<String> qStr = new MyQueue();
    qStr.enqueue("1");
    qStr.enqueue("2");
    qStr.enqueue("3");
    qStr.enqueue("4");
    qStr.enqueue("5");
    qStr.toString(qStr.front);
    qStr.dequeue();
    qStr.toString(qStr.front);



}

}  


public class MyQueue<T>{
MyNode<T> back;
MyNode<T> front;

public MyQueue(){
    back = null;
    front = null;

}
public void enqueue(T payload) {
    if(back == null) {
    MyNode<T> firstnode = new MyNode<T>(payload);
    back = firstnode; 
    front = firstnode;
}
else {
    MyNode<T> addtoback = new MyNode<T>(payload, back.next, null);
    back = addtoback;



 }
}
public String toString(MyNode<T> x) {
System.out.println(x.payload);

if(x.payload == null) {
    return "";
    }
    else{
        return (String) x.payload;
    }
}
public void dequeue() {
if (isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Queue underflow");
} else if (front == back) {
    T payload1 = front.payload;
    front = null;
    back = null;
    System.out.println(payload1);
}

T payload1 = front.payload;
front = front.previous;
System.out.println(payload1);

}

public Boolean isEmpty() {
if(back==null) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}

public int size() {
MyNode<T> k = back;
if(isEmpty()||k.next==null) {
    return 0;
}
k = k.next;
return 1+size();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the `previous` variable in the `MyNode` class.

What is happening is that you set the `front` variable in the `MyQueue` class when you call `enqueue(T)` for the first time. Once you call `dequeue()` for the first time it sets the `front` variable in the `MyQueue` to the `previous` variable in the `MyNode` class which is never set. `front` in the `MyQueue` class becomes null and the next time `toString(MyNode<T>)` is called you get a `NullPointerException`.

That is also why the first call to `toString(MyNode<T>)` doesn't give a `NullPointerException`. `dequeue()` wasn't called yet.